# The attribute table is damaged after OSMFILTER

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, osmfilter

I use osmfilter to extract data from geofabrik.

I had to notice sometimes the attribut table gets "damaged" or rather osmfilter put all relevant data in a section called other tags. from there the data are no use to me anymore (no filtering possible etc.)

I used `keep="railway=platform"` and QGIS, osmfilter and put the .osm file directly in QGIS for further transformation in a geopackage.

How to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Read carefully https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html#configuration and what is said about the osmconf.ini file. It is a bit tricky to convert OSM data into GIS formats. The "all relevant data in one bucket" is the native OSM way.

Comment: you should still be able to do filtering etc. Have a look at QGIS function `hstore_to_map` and then at other `map_` functions

Comment: @JGH I have looked it up but do not really get it. to extract just the platforms I use "select by expression" of this layer. but when I try to get the platforms out is either `NULL` or incorrect syntax. I used `map_get(hstore_to_map("other_tags" ), 'platform' )` but I miss something apparently. where is the mistake?

Comment: Once you have the field and sub-field, you would compare its value, so something like `map_get(hstore_to_map("other_tags" ), 'public_transport' ) = 'platform'`